# Smart cards and Secure channel requirements of Common Criteria (Class FTP)

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

In the second part of *Cammon Criteria* standards, There is a class named **FTP**. In security target of Smart Card and Java cards, it is mentioned that the card must meet these requirements. Below you see two elements of this class for my *JCOP v2.4.2 r3* smart card :

> **6.1.9.10  FTP_ITC.1/CM Inter-TSF trusted channel**
>
> - FTP_ITC.1.1/CM :
>
> The TSF shall provide a communication channel between itself and another
>   trusted IT  product that is logically distinct from other
>   communication channels and provides assured  identification of its end
>   points and protection of the channel data from modification or 
>   disclosure.
>
> - FTP_ITC.1.2/CM : [Editorially Refined]
>
> The TSF shall
>   permit the CAD placed in the card issuer secured environment to 
>   initiate communication via the trusted channel.
>
> - FTP_ITC.1.3/CM
>
> The
>   TSF shall initiate communication via the trusted channel for
>   loading/installing a  new application package on the card. 
>   Application note: There is no dynamic package loading on the Java Card
>   platform. New  packages can be installed on the card only on demand of
>   the card issuer.
>
> **6.1.14.2  FTP_ITC.1/ LifeCycle Inter-TSF Trusted Channel**
>
> - FTP_ITC.1.1/LifeCycle :
>
> The TSF shall provide a communication channel
>   between itself and another trusted IT  product that is logically
>   distinct from other communication channels and provides assured 
>   identification of its end points and protection of the channel data
>   from modification or  disclosure.
>
> - FTP_ITC.1.2/ LifeCycle :
>
> The TSF
>   shall permit [assignment: another trusted IT product] to initiate 
>   communication via the trusted channel.
>
> - FTP_ITC.1.3/ LifeCycle :
>
> The
>   TSF shall initiate communication via the trusted channel for
>   [assignment: setting  the Card Life Cycle State and setting the OS
>   Internal Life Cycle State].

The question is that how could i test the card to see if it meets these requirements or not? Using encryption methods when sending and receiving APDUs to card, is the proof of meeting this method?

Any way, can I send an APDU in an encrypted form to the card? I mean, Can I send SELECT APDU command to card in a encrypted form instead of plain (= 00a40400 ...) ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not the manufacturer of the card you don't have to prove the requirements. You just need to ask for the certification report. You may of course still need to adhere to a Protection Profile / Security Target for you *particular application*. In that case you must make sure that you adhere to the previously established rules above. This can be reviewed and - if for a high enough protection level - audited.

You can send encrypted APDU's to the card if you have the Global Platform keys. Then you can use STORE DATA over the GP secure channel to personalize the application (applet) on the card. Of course, the applet in that case must have been programmed to unwrap the APDU's using the on-card GP API. The SELECT by name however is picked up by the card runtime and should be send in plain.